# Replacing a range within a fixed length file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Looking for some guidance on how to read an input file which is always Fixed Length CR/LF with a fixed length of 200 characters and replace positions 10 - 15.

I'm successfully reading the input file with a StreamReader but struggling with ouputting the new file with the replaced characters I'm getting from a text box.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Updated Code Attempt..  I've used this to read/write delimited files where I appended a value but not sure the approach to use within the while statement to replace characters 10 - 15.

```
Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(tbNewSSF.Text)

Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(IO.File.Open(tbSelectedSSF.Text, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, IO.FileShare.None))

While Not sr.EndOfStream

End While

sw.Flush()
sw.Dispose()
sw.Close()

sr.Dispose()
sr.Close()
```

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: Post revised with what I have to date..

Comment: Why would someone -1 me?  Raise a concern to me or post why its negative..  Eitherway I got it working with the guidance below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the file.  You should also prefer `Using` when dealing with disposables.

Not in front of Visual Studio right now, but something like this (assumes `Option Infer On`)...

```
Using out = New StreamWriter(tbNewSSF.Text)
    For Each line In File.ReadLines(tbSelectedSSF.Text)
        out.WriteLine(
            "{0}{1}{2}",
            line.Substring(0, 9),
            replacementString,
            line.Substring(15)
        )
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I modified the example a bit to break up the string into 2 substrings and rejoin during the output.

Just need a little guidance - THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .ReadLine to read in a single line in to a string (as delimited by the cr/lf), and then use standard string manipulation functions to pull off the parts of that string that you need and rebuild it with your replacements.  After you read the line and edit it you can immediately write it to the new file using a separate writer.